# How can I get my dynamic link to also scroll to an anchor

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have researched this and cannot find an answer. The solutions I have found have not resulted in success.

I am building a WordPress Template and I have a section that contains dynamic tabs. When the user selects a particular tab, the data below it changes accordingly.

However, I cannot get it to scroll down on focus like a normal in-page anchor would do. My relevant code is:

**Link**:

```
<a href="#<?php echo strtolower(substr($string, 0, strpos( $string, ' ') )).$j;?>-content"><span><?php the_sub_field('work_tab_title');?></span></a>`
```

**Anchor**:

```
<div id="<?php echo strtolower(substr($string, 0, strpos( $string, ' ') )).$i;?>-content" class="<?php if($i==1){ echo '';}?> tab-content">
```

My current functionality is working in terms of the tabs changing except for the scroll/focus of the anchor. This would be easier if I could give you the URL but I am not sure if that is against etiquette here, let me know please.

Thank you

---

It has come to the point where a larger section of code is needed for context and better understanding:

```
    <div class="container">

  <ul class="tab-strips">

    <?php $i=0; $j=1; while(has_sub_field('work_slider')):?>

    <?php 

                        $string=get_sub_field('work_tab_title');?>

    <li data-bottom-top="top:-30px; opacity:0;" data-center="top:0px; opacity:1;"><a href="#<?php echo strtolower(substr($string, 0, strpos( $string, ' ') )).$j;?>-content"><span>

      <?php the_sub_field('work_tab_title');?>

      </span></a></li>

    <?php $i++; $j++; endwhile;?>

  </ul>

</div>

<?php $i=1; while(has_sub_field('work_slider')): ?>

<?php $string = get_sub_field('work_tab_title'); ?>

<?php $slider_title = get_sub_field('slider_title'); ?>

<div id="<?php echo strtolower(substr($string, 0, strpos( $string, ' ') )).$i;?>-content" class="<?php if($i==1){ echo '';}?> tab-content">

<?php  ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('<?php echo strtolower(substr($string, 0, strpos( $string, ' ') )).$j;?>-content').scrollIntoView(true);
</script>

  <?php if(get_sub_field('inner_slider')):?>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin-left:9.6%;">
          <h3>
            <?php echo $slider_title; ?>
          </h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider">

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        <ul class="clearfix work-slider-controls" id="work_slider_controls<?php echo $i;?>">

          <?php $j=0; while(has_sub_field('inner_slider')):?>

          <li><a class="work-slider-tab" href="#" data-work-index="<?php echo $i-1;?>" data-slider-index="<?php echo $j;?>" rel="<?php echo $j;?>">

            <?php the_sub_field('work_inner_title');?>

            </a></li>

          <?php $j++; endwhile;?>

        </ul>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div><!-- slider -->
```

Comment: I am now looking into: document.getElementById('MyID').scrollIntoView(true); but obviously we need to make 'MyID' dynamic, is there a way I can use dynamic PHP to declare a variable to use within JavaScript perhaps?

Comment: I'm not sure to see any issue with your code. You simply have `<a href="#foo-content">foo</a>` and `<div id="foo-content">Foo!</div>` there should be no issue with it even with dynamically generated elements.

Comment: is it acceptable to provide you with a link to a live demo of this code?

Comment: As you can see even if all those elements are dynamically inserted - it **works perfectly fine**: http://jsbin.com/qedute/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: urls to websites are not welcome. You have all the needed markup tools to create a valid, minified example that reflects your issue. Usually people creating those examples realize their mistakes :D

Comment: Yes, it SHOULD be working... I'm stumped

Comment: What is `$i` and `$j`?

Comment: Mevius, see edits :)